# Understanding how Getx state update with specific id work with SetState((){})

Tags: flutter, dart, state, flutter-getx, statefulwidget

while discovering `Getx` source code, I faced a piece of code that make me confused, it's not related 100% to `Getx`. it's about `SetState(() {})`

so, in the `Getx` there is a state update that targets only the widgets with a specific id:

```
Disposer addListenerId(Object? key, GetStateUpdate listener) {
_updatersGroupIds![key] ??= <GetStateUpdate>[];
_updatersGroupIds![key]!.add(listener);
return () => _updatersGroupIds![key]!.remove(listener);
```

}

the `_updatersGroupIds` is a `HashMap<Object?, List<void Function()>>?`.

and when calling it from the `StatefulWidget`, like this :

```
controller?.addListenerId(
        widget.id,
        setState(() {}),
      );
```

the `id` is passed from a property in the widget call, **and as you see it's passing the whole `SetState(() {})` of that `StatefulWidget` in the function**!

so the `_updatersGroupIds` will be something like this :

```
_updatersGroupIds == {
  "idExample": [
    SetState(() {}),
  ]
};
```

right?

what confused me is when we try to update the state we call the `update` method from the controller with desirables ids to update :

```
update(["idExample"]);
```

this is implemented as follows:

```
   void update([List<Object> ids]) {
    for (final id in ids) {
      if (_updatersGroupIds!.containsKey(id)) {
        final listGroup = _updatersGroupIds![id]!;
        for (var item in listGroup) {
          item();
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

so what I understand is that when we get the "exampleId" in the `_updatersGroupIds` hashmap, we iterate over all the `SetState(() {})` in that list, by calling them

so what I'm expecting vs what happens :

**what I'm expecting:**
that since we called all the `SetState(() {})` in that `List`, it will update the `State` of all `StateFulWidget` in the whole app, or at least it will update the last `StatefulWidget` we run that function from.

**what is happening:**
it updates only the `StatefulWidget` with the same "exampleId", and nothing else

my question is: how when we store the `SetState(() {})` of multiple widgets like :

```
List<void Function()> staterList = [SetState(() {}), SetState(() {}), SetState(() {})];
```

when we call the second one:

```
staterList[1].call();
```

how does it know that it should update only the `StatefulWidget` where that `SetState((){})` came from and nothing else?

another format of question:
is there some referencing set on `SetState(() {})`, so that it knows the `StateFulWidget` where it came from when we call it somewhere outside?

please share your knowledge with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ListNotifierSingle**

lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/list_notifier.dart: `class ListNotifierSingle = ListNotifier with ListNotifierSingleMixin;` we care mostly about `ListNotifierSingleMixin`


**ListNotifierSingleMixin**

lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/list_notifier.dart: `mixin ListNotifierSingleMixin on Listenable` is referenced in `_updatersGroupIds`


**GetStateUpdate**

lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/list_notifier.dart: `typedef GetStateUpdate = void Function();` This is basically the same as [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html), you could put any function that is `void` with no parameters, but that may produce undesired results.


**_updatersGroupIds**

Your definition of `_updatersGroupIds` is close, but incorrect. `_updatersGroupIds` is a `Object` reference key, mapped to a reference to a `ListNotifierSingleMixin`. `_updatersGroupIds` would be

```dart
{
  Object():  ListNotifierSingle(), // references to instances of each object
  Object():  ListNotifierSingle(), 
}
```

**addListenerId**

When running the below code, an `Object` reference key, and `ListNotifierSingle` reference are added to the `_updatersGroupIds`. Then the instance of `ListNotifierSingle` has it's `addListener` function run, which adds the `setState` function to the `ListNotifierSingle` instance's `_updaters`. See the below functions with comments

```dart
controller?.addListenerId(
        widget.id,
        setState(() {}),
      );
```

```dart
Disposer addListenerId(Object? key, GetStateUpdate listener) {

  // init if is null
  _updatersGroupIds![key] ??= ListNotifierSingle();

  // pass listener (setState) to ListNotifierSingle reference addListener 
  // function, this is defined in ListNotifierSingleMixin
  return _updatersGroupIds![key]!.addListener(listener);
}
```

```dart
@override
Disposer addListener(GetStateUpdate listener) {
  // no disposed
  assert(_debugAssertNotDisposed());
  // add setState to list
  _updaters!.add(listener);
  // return a function that removes setState from list (_updaters) when called
  return () => _updaters!.remove(listener);
}
```

**update**

lib/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart: `void update([List<Object>? ids, bool condition = true])`, which is part of `abstract class GetxController extends ListNotifier with GetLifeCycleMixin`, which extends `ListNotifier`, which extends `ListNotifierGroupMixin`; therefore, `refreshGroup` is defined under `ListNotifierGroupMixin`.

When calling `update(["idExample"]);` all passed ids are refreshed using `refreshGroup` in `update`, see below.

```dart
  void update([List<Object>? ids, bool condition = true]) {
    // not called in our example
    if (!condition) {
      return;
    }
    // not called in our example
    if (ids == null) {
      refresh();
      // called in our example, defined under ListNotifierGroupMixin
      // all passed ids are refreshed using refreshGroup
    } else {
      for (final id in ids) {
        refreshGroup(id);
      }
    }
  }
```

`refreshGroup` calls `_notifyGroupUpdate`

```dart
  void refreshGroup(Object id) {
    assert(_debugAssertNotDisposed());
    _notifyGroupUpdate(id);
  }
```

`_notifyGroupUpdate` checks if passed id is in `_updatersGroupIds`, and if it is it runs `_notifyUpdate` function for the single instance of `ListNotifierSingleMixin` with the key id in the `_updatersGroupIds` map.

```dart
  void _notifyGroupUpdate(Object id) {
    // check if exists
    if (_updatersGroupIds!.containsKey(id)) {
      // run _updatersGroupIds function for specified 
      // ListNotifierSingleMixin instance
      _updatersGroupIds![id]!._notifyUpdate();
    }
  }
```

`_notifyUpdate` iterates over all the functions in `_updaters`, which are for a single instance of ListNotifierSingleMixin, which in our case is the one with key `"idExample"`. There should only be one function in `_updaters` in our example, which is the setState function of the widget in our example. There will only be multiple values in `_updaters` if you call `controller?.addListenerId` with the same id more than once.

```dart
  void _notifyUpdate() {
    // if (_microtaskVersion == _version) {
    //   _microtaskVersion++;
    //   scheduleMicrotask(() {
    //     _version++;
    //     _microtaskVersion = _version;

    // make sure list is not null
    final list = _updaters?.toList() ?? [];

    //  iterate over functions in _updaters queue
    // when the function is run it removes it's contained function
    // from _updaters, see addListener. The inner function should be 
    // setState
    for (var element in list) {
      element();
    }
    //   });
    // }
  }
```

Comment: Hi CatTrain, thank you so mush for your answer, it really worth reading, but what I want to understand is why when we iterate over the _updaters?.toList() which will run specific SetState((){}) s updates only the widget where it comes the first place, I mean since we just call it, how it knows and filters which widget to update and not the other widgets

Comment: because like I see, they are all the same SetState((){]), how calling one does update only a specific widget and not all of them ?

Comment: and again, thank you so mush for responding, I will really appreciate if you could guide me on the way this mechanism works

Comment: @Gwhyyy "because like I see, they are all the same SetState((){])", this is false. When the `setState` functions are added to `_updaters` it is a reference to a specific `State`'s `setState` function. The `setState` functions are called by reference. All languages use references at some level, you should read about them. [Reference (C++)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Oh, so every SetState(() {}) has a pointer to the State object of StatefulWidget, and when we call a specific one, it updates the State object where it points

Comment: I can understand it now, before accepting this as the right answer, may I ask to include this in the answer? so it will be on the big screen for everyone who asks the same question.

Comment: @Gwhyyy I would like to emphasize a reference, and not a pointer. [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable)